# Changing reserved characters to their Percent-Encodings

Tags: php, html

I have a text input field that is used for a search. When the user's search includes a restrictive character [explained in wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters)] like the # sign or the ! symbol, the site gives an error, because the url features such a character.

Example: The code appends the search query to a web address

```
    <head>
    <?php <meta name="http-equiv" content="0; url=http://www.mysite.com/search.php?query=.$_GET['query']" ?>
   </head>
```

Where the variable "query" is the search query.

If the user searches for #, the resulting webpage would be http://www.mysite.com/search.php?query="#", obviously generating an error.

Comment: [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode)

Comment: Your posted code contains a parse error; are you sure that's your *actual* code?

Comment: The code didn't create any parse error. It is used in a website I've created called 'Googol2' [http://www.hussainkhalil.tk/Public/Googol2] This could be because the version of PHP my server has is rather old.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode)

I only post this as an answer because your code has some syntax errors I also fixed.

```
<head>
<meta name="http-equiv" content="0; url=http://www.mysite.com/search.php?query=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['query']); ?>">
</head>
```

Comment: @SanBergam uh, the code you posted in your question will very definitely throw a parse error. It will throw an error right at the `<` opening tag of the meta tag. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in.."

Comment: I'm a PHP novice... but you can see my code at http://www.hussainkhalil.tk/Public/Googol2 . I'm not sure why the code works.

Comment: @SanBergam perhaps it works because the code in that link has no meta tag like what you posted here?

Comment: Actually, you were right. The entire <meta> tag was inside the PHP echo... sorry